# Running Different Modules on Tomcat/Server

Tags: tomcat

I have started working on my own project, but I am stuck due to the lack of enough knowledge. I am wondering how I can make 2 different modules to co-operate on the server. Below are some details on the 2 modules of my project

1. Back end handling where i can do all
   content handling as well as other
   admin task a console which will be
   capable of handling everything from
   ceating importing contents to
   everything.
2. User end which is only an interface
   to the end user to use the
   application. to visualize the things
   its kinda e-commerce application one
   is back office management and other
   is user end of web-shop.

As you can see, the 2 modules are very much related but I doesn't want to combine them together into a single module. I want develop them independently since admin is one which is core and it will also going to serve user interface.

My question is how i can develop two module independently but on the other hand i want them to co-operate to accomplish the task as a whole.

Really sorry in advance if i am not making any sense.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no real need to separate them into two web applications. Logical separation is all what you need. Logically group your application into independent modules and just bring them all together into a single web-application during the build. Also read about [MVC and layered architecture](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=167844)

Comment: @Pangea: i am doing this till now planning to put everything in one webapp with sperating them with well defined names but was doubtful is this a good way to go?

Comment: This is the preferred way to go but not with well defined names but with well defined boundaries i.e. good LAYERED architecture.

Comment: @Pangea: Can you please explian what exactly you mean by well defined boundaries?

Comment: For e.g hide your database CRUD (create/read/update/delete) operations in a persistence layer and let the service layer talk to the persistence layer. If your UI layer (JSP) directly accessed the DB then you doesn't have the well defined boundary.

Comment: Agrre that is already in place my JSP will only talk to Struts2 action component which will in term talk to BO and they will do all the heavy duty work like talking to DAO and persistance layers and get work done

Comment: Then you need to explain your question in a different way by being very specific. Your question was very generic. Think it this way: What are you solving by separating them into two webapps?

Answer (score 0):

Since two of your requirements are a Tomcat server, a web application and a web admin interface, I recommend trying django web framework.

You can use django web framework to have web admin interface automatically. Django has inbuild support for customizable web admin interface and your built user interface.

Have a read at http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial02/ for more info.

I am a bit unclear about your other requirements but if it's a typical web application and you need a web admin interface django is one way to go.

Comment: My framework requirements have already in place my question is specific to design

Comment: Well Struts2,Spring,Hibernate for there respective specilize areas :)

Comment: I am curious why struts 2? If you are already using spring then why can't you use Spring MVC?

Comment: Yes matter of choice Struts2 is my natural choice for MVC though i am not against for Spring MVC but with respect to tag lib and ajax support its good in Struts2 and may be i am lazy to learn Spring MVC :)